# negative margin effecting DIV in IE8?

Tags: css

http://chocolatvitale.com

in IE 8 the slideshow at the top overflows to exactly below the div its supposed to be contained inside. does it have something to do with the negative margin?

**Container div:**

```
#header{
   background:#190000;
   width:1024px;
   height:216px;
```

}

**Slideshow divs:**

```
.slideshow { 
    float:left;
    height: 216px;
    width: 1023px; 
    margin-top:-192px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1; 
}

.slideshow img {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    height:216px;
    width:1023px; 
    border: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.  Your negative margin is moving your `.slideshow` container up 192px, which puts it basically out of view.  Only 24px of each image is showing:

```
216px height - 192px margin = 24px visible
```

If you remove the negative top margin from the CSS, it will display correctly:

```
.slideshow { 
    float:left;
    height: 216px;
    width: 1023px; 

    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1; 
}
```